# Where is stocked my Sqlite Database

Tags: android

I am developing an application on Android where I need to use a database (SqLite). However, I don't know where it is saved and even if the database is really created... How can I ensure it?

Thanks

Comment: `Context#getDatabasePath`

Comment: @pskink Could you please explain a bit more... Thanks !

Comment: what to explain? whats unclear in that method?

Comment: What should I write in the code to see the database path?

Comment: What he means is to use `getDatabasePath()` method from `Activity` instance. That will return the database path. @pskink You should make that an answer, your comment is way better than any existing answer here.

Comment: well explained demo.https://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite database is by default stored at below path:

data/data/application_package_name/databases/your_db_file

However this path is private to the application and you cannot access it unless the device is rooted. You can have a look at this path when you run you application in emulator and then access above path using 'android device manager' from Android Studio.

Go to DDMS -> file explorer -> data -> data -> see your package name -> databases -> here your database file. (In the upper right, choose "Pull file" from device.) Export it and open through an Sqlite database connector.

Comment: You're right except for the .db extension and if future Android versions change the path.

Comment: @m0skit0 could you please highlight me with the correct extension.

Comment: There's no extension unless you name the database with an extension. File extensions are Windows stuff.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @m0skit0 I read on this and updated the answer. cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends upon your code implementation. You can create Database in internal(that is app memory) or in external memory as well. Well in case of internal memory the database is not visible in directory structure while in external case you can see database file physically.